# In Python, how to do groupby + arrange + mutate (ifelse) like R?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataset:

```
ID      Date     Flag      Price     Flag_Amt     Factor
1      1/1/10     NA        20          NA          NA
1      1/2/10     3         20.2        1.05        .5
1      1/3/10     NA        19.2        NA          NA
2      1/1/10     5         12          6.50        1.3
2      1/2/10     NA        12.6        NA          NA
2      1/2/10     NA        13          NA          NA 
3      1/1/10     NA        100         NA          NA
3      1/2/10     5         88          16.7        .88
3      1/3/10     NA        90          NA          NA
```

and I have the following R dplyr code:

```
df = df %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(Date) %>% mutate(New_Factor = ifelse(Flag == 5, (Flag_Amt/Price), Factor))
```

which would yield the following results:

```
ID      Date     Flag      Price     Flag_Amt     Factor    New_Factor
1      1/1/10     NA        20          NA          NA         NA 
1      1/2/10     3         20.2        10.1        .5         .5
1      1/3/10     NA        19.2        NA          NA         NA        
2      1/1/10     5         12          6.50        1.3        1.85
2      1/2/10     NA        12.6        NA          NA         NA
2      1/2/10     NA        13          NA          NA         NA
3      1/1/10     NA        100         NA          NA         NA        
3      1/2/10     5         88          16.7        .88        5.27
3      1/3/10     NA        90          NA          NA         NA
```

However, I am having a difficult time trying to replicate this in Python pandas.

Below is some of the code I have tried and the error I have received:

```
df['New_Factor'] = df.groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda x: (x.Price/x.Flag_Amt) if x.Flag == 5 else (x.Factor)))
```

Error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is there some other way, perhaps using `.transform()` along with `np.where()` to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: reason for doing groupby and arranging by date ?

Comment: group by and arrange: essentially after isolating the effect of flag 5 for each ID.. im gonna create my own factor for each ID.. so group by and dates are important

Comment: data['New_Factor'] = np.where(data['Flag'] == 5, data['Price']/data['Flag_Amt'], data['Factor'])... gives the same result

Comment: *date* is not used in any way and no aggregation is being run so `groupby` or `group_by` is not even needed

Comment: just do what @iamklaus said: `df['New_Factor'] = np.where(df['Flag'] == 5, df['Price']/df['Flag_Amt'], df['Factor'])`

Comment: thanks for the explanation @iamklaus

Comment: thanks @Parfait now I understand

Comment: how would I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Your result from R code should look like this:

```r
r$> library(tibble)
r$> library(dplyr)
r$> df = tribble( 
            ~ID,  ~Date,   ~Flag,  ~Price,  ~Flag_Amt, ~Factor, 
        1,     '1/1/10', NA,      20,       NA,         NA, 
        1,     '1/2/10', 3,       20.2,     1.05,       .5, 
        1,     '1/3/10', NA,      19.2,     NA,         NA, 
        2,     '1/1/10', 5,       12,       6.50,       1.3, 
        2,     '1/2/10', NA,      12.6,     NA,         NA, 
        2,     '1/2/10', NA,      13,       NA,         NA , 
        3,     '1/1/10', NA,      100,      NA,         NA, 
        3,     '1/2/10', 5,       88,       16.7,       .88, 
        3,     '1/3/10', NA,      90,       NA,         NA
    )                                                  
r$> df
# A tibble: 9 x 6
     ID Date    Flag Price Flag_Amt Factor
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 1/1/10    NA  20      NA     NA   
2     1 1/2/10     3  20.2     1.05   0.5 
3     1 1/3/10    NA  19.2    NA     NA   
4     2 1/1/10     5  12       6.5    1.3 
5     2 1/2/10    NA  12.6    NA     NA   
6     2 1/2/10    NA  13      NA     NA   
7     3 1/1/10    NA 100      NA     NA   
8     3 1/2/10     5  88      16.7    0.88
9     3 1/3/10    NA  90      NA     NA   

r$> df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
      arrange(Date) %>% 
      mutate(New_Factor = ifelse(Flag == 5, (Flag_Amt/Price), Factor))
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Date    Flag Price Flag_Amt Factor New_Factor
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 1/1/10    NA  20      NA     NA        NA    
2     2 1/1/10     5  12       6.5    1.3       0.542
3     3 1/1/10    NA 100      NA     NA        NA    
4     1 1/2/10     3  20.2     1.05   0.5       0.5  
5     2 1/2/10    NA  12.6    NA     NA        NA    
6     2 1/2/10    NA  13      NA     NA        NA    
7     3 1/2/10     5  88      16.7    0.88      0.190
8     1 1/3/10    NA  19.2    NA     NA        NA    
9     3 1/3/10    NA  90      NA     NA        NA
```

Here is how it looks like using python package [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), without digging into pandas APIs:

```py
>>> from datar.all import (
...     f, NA, tribble, c, rep,
...     group_by, arrange, mutate, if_else
... )
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.ID,  f.Date,   f.Flag,  f.Price,  f.Flag_Amt, f.Factor,
...     1,     '1/1/10', NA,      20,       NA,         NA,
...     1,     '1/2/10', 3,       20.2,     1.05,       .5,
...     1,     '1/3/10', NA,      19.2,     NA,         NA,
...     2,     '1/1/10', 5,       12,       6.50,       1.3,
...     2,     '1/2/10', NA,      12.6,     NA,         NA,
...     2,     '1/2/10', NA,      13,       NA,         NA ,
...     3,     '1/1/10', NA,      100,      NA,         NA,
...     3,     '1/2/10', 5,       88,       16.7,       .88,
...     3,     '1/3/10', NA,      90,       NA,         NA,
... )
>>> df
   ID    Date  Flag  Price  Flag_Amt  Factor
0   1  1/1/10   NaN   20.0       NaN     NaN
1   1  1/2/10   3.0   20.2      1.05    0.50
2   1  1/3/10   NaN   19.2       NaN     NaN
3   2  1/1/10   5.0   12.0      6.50    1.30
4   2  1/2/10   NaN   12.6       NaN     NaN
5   2  1/2/10   NaN   13.0       NaN     NaN
6   3  1/1/10   NaN  100.0       NaN     NaN
7   3  1/2/10   5.0   88.0     16.70    0.88
8   3  1/3/10   NaN   90.0       NaN     NaN
>>> df = (
...     df >> 
...         group_by(f.ID) >> 
...         arrange(f.Date) >> 
...         mutate(New_Factor = if_else(f.Flag == 5, (f.Flag_Amt/f.Price), f.Factor))
... )
>>> df
   ID    Date  Flag  Price  Flag_Amt  Factor New_Factor
0   1  1/1/10   NaN   20.0       NaN     NaN        NaN
1   2  1/1/10   5.0   12.0      6.50    1.30   0.541667
2   3  1/1/10   NaN  100.0       NaN     NaN        NaN
3   1  1/2/10   3.0   20.2      1.05    0.50        0.5
4   2  1/2/10   NaN   12.6       NaN     NaN        NaN
5   2  1/2/10   NaN   13.0       NaN     NaN        NaN
6   3  1/2/10   5.0   88.0     16.70    0.88   0.189773
7   1  1/3/10   NaN   19.2       NaN     NaN        NaN
8   3  1/3/10   NaN   90.0       NaN     NaN        NaN
[Groups: ['ID'] (n=3)]
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow - you answered 2 years later, but I appreciate you answering. Thank you

Comment: @yungpadewon I just came up with this package recently :)

Comment: whoa great. I will surely check it out. Cheers